# Android Map: How to animate polyline on Map?

Tags: android, google-maps, animation, maps, polyline

When I plot my polyline on Map from point A -> B, I have a requirement to draw the polyline with animation. As if from A-> B the polyline keeps on drawing.

I have used below link for reference:

```
https://github.com/amalChandran/google-maps-route-animation
```

Using the solution I am able to animate the polyline, but the polyline itself is not proper. It doesn't go through road. Original APK of the solution also has the same bug.

Can someone pls help me with a suitable solution

Comment: Hi. have you got the fix for this issue becz i am having the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try with this reference also 
https://github.com/mohak1712/UberUX?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=6129

ValueAnimator - For animating overlays and polylines

```
ValueAnimator tAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
       tAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
       tAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART);
       tAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
       tAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
           @Override
           public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
              // animate here
           }
       });
```

PolyLines - For drawing lines on map

```
 PolylineOptions greyOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        greyOptions.width(10);
        greyOptions.color(Color.GRAY);
        greyOptions.startCap(new SquareCap());
        greyOptions.endCap(new SquareCap());
        greyOptions.jointType(ROUND);
        greyPolyLine = mMap.addPolyline(greyOptions);
```

Comment: @Sayan Manna can you help. i dont understand how to link the ValueAnimator to the PolylineOptions your using. you declared a simple tAnimator but how are you  referencing it in other places. i would like my polyline to animate like this: https://streamable.com/h569z

Comment: @j2emanue below link may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43661843/how-to-draw-uber-polyline

Comment: excellent example,  not about animation though but i really appreciate the link.  you spawned new ideas for me.

Comment: @GowthamanM where you able to use a value animator with your polyline ? how ?

Answer (score 2):

Enable Direction API from Google Console. Replace `google_api_key_app` in `strings.xml`

```
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.SquareCap;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import static com.google.android.gms.maps.model.JointType.ROUND;

public class GetPathFromLocation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, PolylineOptions> {

    private Context context;
    private String TAG = "GetPathFromLocation";
    private LatLng source, destination;
    private ArrayList<LatLng> wayPoint;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private boolean animatePath, repeatDrawingPath;
    private DirectionPointListener resultCallback;

    //https://www.mytrendin.com/draw-route-two-locations-google-maps-android/
    //https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/google-maps-draw-path-two-points-using-google-directions-google-map-android-api-v2/

    public GetPathFromLocation(Context context, LatLng source, LatLng destination, ArrayList<LatLng> wayPoint, GoogleMap mMap, boolean animatePath, boolean repeatDrawingPath, DirectionPointListener resultCallback) {
        this.context = context;
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.wayPoint = wayPoint;
        this.mMap = mMap;
        this.animatePath = animatePath;
        this.repeatDrawingPath = repeatDrawingPath;
        this.resultCallback = resultCallback;
    }

    synchronized public String getUrl(LatLng source, LatLng dest, ArrayList<LatLng> wayPoint) {

        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?sensor=false&mode=driving&origin="
                + source.latitude + "," + source.longitude + "&destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;
        for (int centerPoint = 0; centerPoint < wayPoint.size(); centerPoint++) {
            if (centerPoint == 0) {
                url = url + "&waypoints=optimize:true|" + wayPoint.get(centerPoint).latitude + "," + wayPoint.get(centerPoint).longitude;
            } else {
                url = url + "|" + wayPoint.get(centerPoint).latitude + "," + wayPoint.get(centerPoint).longitude;
            }
        }
        url = url + "&key=" + context.getString(R.string.google_api_key_app);

        Helper.showLog("Direction_URL: " + url);

        return url;
    }

    public int getRandomColor() {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        return Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
    }

    @Override
    protected PolylineOptions doInBackground(String... url) {

        String data;

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                URL directionUrl = new URL(getUrl(source, destination, wayPoint));
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) directionUrl.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuffer.append(line);
                }

                data = stringBuffer.toString();
                bufferedReader.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception : " + e.toString());
                return null;
            } finally {
                inputStream.close();
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "Background Task data : " + data);

            //Second AsyncTask

            JSONObject jsonObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                // Starts parsing data
                DirectionHelper helper = new DirectionHelper();
                routes = helper.parse(jsonObject);
                Log.e(TAG, "Executing Routes : "/*, routes.toString()*/);

                //Third AsyncTask

                ArrayList<LatLng> points;
                PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

                // Traversing through all the routes
                for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++) {
                    points = new ArrayList<>();
                    lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                    // Fetching i-th route
                    List<HashMap<String, String>> path = routes.get(i);

                    // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                    for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                        double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                        double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                        LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                        points.add(position);
                    }

                    // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                    lineOptions.addAll(points);
                    lineOptions.width(8);
                    lineOptions.color(Color.BLACK);
                    //lineOptions.color(getRandomColor());

                    if (animatePath) {
                        final ArrayList<LatLng> finalPoints = points;
                        ((AppCompatActivity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                PolylineOptions polylineOptions;
                                final Polyline greyPolyLine, blackPolyline;
                                final ValueAnimator polylineAnimator;

                                LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                                for (LatLng latLng : finalPoints) {
                                    builder.include(latLng);
                                }
                                polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                                polylineOptions.color(Color.GRAY);
                                polylineOptions.width(8);
                                polylineOptions.startCap(new SquareCap());
                                polylineOptions.endCap(new SquareCap());
                                polylineOptions.jointType(ROUND);
                                polylineOptions.addAll(finalPoints);
                                greyPolyLine = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

                                polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                                polylineOptions.width(8);
                                polylineOptions.color(Color.BLACK);
                                polylineOptions.startCap(new SquareCap());
                                polylineOptions.endCap(new SquareCap());
                                polylineOptions.zIndex(5f);
                                polylineOptions.jointType(ROUND);

                                blackPolyline = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
                                polylineAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 100);
                                polylineAnimator.setDuration(2000);
                                polylineAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                                polylineAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                                        List<LatLng> points = greyPolyLine.getPoints();
                                        int percentValue = (int) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                                        int size = points.size();
                                        int newPoints = (int) (size * (percentValue / 100.0f));
                                        List<LatLng> p = points.subList(0, newPoints);
                                        blackPolyline.setPoints(p);
                                    }
                                });

                                polylineAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                        if (repeatDrawingPath) {
                                            List<LatLng> greyLatLng = greyPolyLine.getPoints();
                                            if (greyLatLng != null) {
                                                greyLatLng.clear();

                                            }
                                            polylineAnimator.start();
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                                        polylineAnimator.cancel();
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                                    }
                                });
                                polylineAnimator.start();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    Log.e(TAG, "PolylineOptions Decoded");
                }

                // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
                if (lineOptions != null) {
                    return lineOptions;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception in Executing Routes : " + e.toString());
                return null;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Background Task Exception : " + e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(PolylineOptions polylineOptions) {
        super.onPostExecute(polylineOptions);
        if (resultCallback != null && polylineOptions != null)
            resultCallback.onPath(polylineOptions);
    }
}
```

**DirectionHelper.java**

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class DirectionHelper {

    public List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject) {

        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONArray jRoutes;
        JSONArray jLegs;
        JSONArray jSteps;

        try {

            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            /** Traversing all routes */
            for (int i = 0; i < jRoutes.length(); i++) {
                jLegs = ((JSONObject) jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                List path = new ArrayList<>();

                /** Traversing all legs */
                for (int j = 0; j < jLegs.length(); j++) {
                    jSteps = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for (int k = 0; k < jSteps.length(); k++) {
                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                        /** Traversing all points */
                        for (int l = 0; l < list.size(); l++) {
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString((list.get(l)).latitude));
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString((list.get(l)).longitude));
                            path.add(hm);
                        }
                    }
                    routes.add(path);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }


        return routes;
    }

    //Method to decode polyline points
    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }
}
```

**DirectionPointListener.java**

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

public interface DirectionPointListener {
    public void onPath(PolylineOptions polyLine);
}
```

**Use in Activity or Fragment**

```
ArrayList<LatLng> wayPoint = new ArrayList<>();
GoogleMap mMap;
LatLng source = new LatLng(xx.xxxx, yy.yyyy);
LatLng destination = new LatLng(xx.xxxx, yy.yyyy);

new GetPathFromLocation(context, source, destination, wayPoint, mMap, true, false, new DirectionPointListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPath(PolylineOptions polyLine) {
            mMap.addPolyline(polyLine);
        }
    }).execute();
```

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="google_api_key_app">Place_Your_API_Key</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also draw routes without polylines. Using google maps projection APIs you can draw it over an overlay layer. Check the [repo](https://github.com/amalChandran/trail-android) for an example.

[image]

Comment: it is possible to draw path with animation using overlay?

Comment: Yes. This is how the route is drawn on the overlay. Using canvas drawing APIs. @BloodLoss

Comment: this works good, with one issues when you rotate map. it sucks arc and projection are moved away from point where were drawn. entire screen looks mess

Comment: sure, give me few minutes please

Comment: @AttiqueUrRehman this issue is fixed in a different branch on the same repo. Ill try to release a new version with this fix over this weekend.

Comment: how can we hide the projection of arc? can add this too?
@amalBit any estimated date when it will be available in release

Comment: @AttiqueUrRehman Can you raise this as a bug on github? I am not sure what you mean by the projection of arc.  I can't really promise you a date. I'll try to spend some time this weekend.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void drawRoute()
    {
        mGoogleApiProvider.getDirections(mOrigenLatLng, mDestinoLatLng)
                .enqueue(new Callback<String>()
                         {
                             @Override
                             public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response)
                             {
                                 try
                                 {
                                     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body());
                                     JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
                                     JSONObject route = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                     JSONObject polylines = route.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
                                     String points = polylines.getString("points");
                                     mPolylineList = DecodificarPuntos.decodificarPoly(points);

                                     mPolylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                                     mPolylineOptions.width(10f);
                                     mPolylineOptions.color(Color.parseColor("#191a23"));
                                     mPolylineOptions.startCap(new SquareCap());
                                     mPolylineOptions.endCap(new SquareCap());
                                     mPolylineOptions.jointType(ROUND);

                                     mPolylineOptions.addAll(mPolylineList);

                                     blackPolyLine = mMap.addPolyline(mPolylineOptions);


                                     PolylineOptions greyOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                                     greyOptions.width(10f);
                                     greyOptions.color(Color.GRAY);
                                     greyOptions.startCap(new SquareCap());
                                     greyOptions.endCap(new SquareCap());
                                     greyOptions.jointType(ROUND);

                                     greyPolyLine = mMap.addPolyline(greyOptions);

                                     animatePolyLine();

                                 }
                                 catch(Exception e)
                                 {
                                     Log.e("Error: ", Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
                                 }

                             }
                             @Override
                             public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t)
                             {

                             }
                         }
                );
    }

    private void animatePolyLine()
    {
        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 100);
        animator.setDuration(1000);
        animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {

                List<LatLng> latLngList = blackPolyLine.getPoints();
                int initialPointSize = latLngList.size();
                int animatedValue = (int) animator.getAnimatedValue();
                int newPoints = (animatedValue * mPolylineList.size()) / 100;

                if (initialPointSize < newPoints ) {
                    latLngList.addAll(mPolylineList.subList(initialPointSize, newPoints));
                    blackPolyLine.setPoints(latLngList);
                }


            }
        });

        animator.addListener(polyLineAnimationListener);
        animator.start();
    }

    Animator.AnimatorListener polyLineAnimationListener = new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

            addMarker(mPolylineList.get(mPolylineList.size()-1));
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator)
        {
            List<LatLng> blackLatLng = blackPolyLine.getPoints();
            List<LatLng> greyLatLng = greyPolyLine.getPoints();

            greyLatLng.clear();
            greyLatLng.addAll(blackLatLng);
            blackLatLng.clear();

            blackPolyLine.setPoints(blackLatLng);
            greyPolyLine.setPoints(greyLatLng);

            blackPolyLine.setZIndex(2);

            animator.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator)
        {
        }
    };

    private void addMarker(LatLng destination) {

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(destination)
                .draggable(false)
                .flat(false)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(marcadorPersonalizadoDestino("Destino", mExtraDestino,
                        mExtraTiempo, mExtraTipoDeTiempo, mExtraDistancia, mExtraTipoDeDistancia)
                ));

        mMap.addMarker(options);

    }
```

Comment: it's working and i have not added addMarker(mPolylineList.get(mPolylineList.size()-1)); this line, issue is when I change my source and destination still old poly line is available. How to clear old poly line path ?

Comment: Yes, I got the answer after adding these line if (animator != null) {
                animator.cancel();
                animator.removeAllListeners();
            }