# Draw a curved line by GMSPolyline google maps ios sdk

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, path, polyline

I want to draw a curved line between two markers (something like Uber) but there's no method for doing that.
is there any idea?

Comment: should it be shortest path between two ?

Comment: @SuryaKantSharma does't mattet just to be curved

Comment: any path means ?

Comment: any curved line between two point

Comment: @Mehrdad Yes only curve line between two points without using google API because that will not work if you have two different country coordinates.

Comment: iOS Swift Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53569754/6593774

Comment: @Rouny tnx a lot :)

Comment: @Mehrdad It would be really nice of you, if you can vote my answer at the above link if it had really helped you in any way.

Comment: @Rouny i solved that problem long time ago...but you're answer is useful for others... so i vote :)

Comment: @Mehrdad Thanks mate