# How to draw curve shape polyline in GoogleMap like Uber share in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I want to draw **curve shape** polyline not a straight line between two locations. **If the first location is India and the second is the US**. **Then no route provided by Google API**. But I have two lats/longs, I want to draw a curve starts from India and end to the US.[image]

Comment: please check this link:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189242/draw-a-curved-line-by-gmspolyline-google-maps-ios-sdk

Comment: @VDPurohit Above link which you have give that not fulfill the requirement. I don't want the path given by Google. If you have two different country location then google API driving path not working for this.

Comment: @VDPurohit Dude at least mark this question upvote so that other can show interest on this.

Comment: iOS Swift Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53569754/6593774

Comment: Has anyone done this in iOS?