# How to Draw a curved polyline like uber , facebook in GMSMapView for ios Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, polyline

I want to draw a curved line between two endpoints (something like facebook, uber).

I have tried this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/53569754/4693326 but not getting the exact result.i have also attached the file for reference.is there any idea?

[image]