# How to animate a Polyline using the osmdroid library in Android?

Tags: android, animation, osmdroid, polyline

I want to animate a Polyline consisting of many GeoPoints using the osmdroid library. I found some answers to this question already like this one: [Android Map: How to animate polyline on Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43292753/android-map-how-to-animate-polyline-on-map)

But most of them are for Google Maps and not for OpenStreetMap. So can someone give me a clue how exactly can I achieve this using osmdroid?